# Easy multicolored text in Java

Tags: java, swing, text, colors

After writing a console application (For mundane I/O tasks not worth mentioning here), I decided I needed to make the text multicolored for readability. I would've liked to keep it in a command prompt, being inexperienced with Swing, but as far as I could figure there was no way to do that, I looked around the Swing API and can't find anything.

Ideally, I'd be able to use something like

```
for(int i=0; i<aString.length(); i++){
    if(aString.charAt(i) == '?'){
        String pre = aString.substring(0,i);
        String post = aString.substring(i);
        aString = pre + red("?") + post;    //As you can see by red("?"), I have no idea what I'm doing
    }
}
```

so that I could just loop through the text I would have previously printed, insert the coloring information, and display it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Method, class, snippet, anything?

Comment: i think there may be a console portability issue since not every console can handle color and color markup. Linux has it's `ncurses`, but does it has Java API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would've liked to keep it in a command prompt, being inexperienced with Swing

You might get some ideas from [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can output your string in html format adding  tag where coloring is expected. Then assign the HTML to JLabel or JTextPane.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [swing api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html)

[Link](http://java.comsci.us/examples/swing/JLabel.html) is a small example to use all the functionalities available in `JLabel` including the color of text in it.

If you want to just display text in different colors then:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass extends JPanel {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = this.getPreferredSize();
    int fontSize = 20;

    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));

    g.setColor(Color.red);

    g.drawString("Hello 1", 10, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.black);

    g.drawString("Hello 2", 30, 50);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MainClass());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```